# Exact number of times that a character should repeat Regex

Tags: regex

I have an exercise in formal languages, of which we work with Regex, the exercise is to validate a chain that has exactly four 1s, for example:

chain 1: 0110101000 - **valid**;

chain 2: 010110 - **invalid**;

chain 3: 011011011 - **invalid**;

What I've been able to do so far has been to validate a string with four or more 1s, but I have not been able to determine exactly how many times a given character should repeat:

Here is the expression that I have been able to develop so far: `/(\S*1){4}.*/`

This expression validates strings longer than four 1s, I need to validate a string that has exactly four 1s.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Try `^[^1]*(1[^1]*){4}$`. Anchors at both ends are necessary. I'm sure this question has been asked many times before. I'll mark this as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?:0*1){4}0*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhnnKc/1)

The scheme is: `^(?:<ALL_BUT_ONE>*<ONE>){<LIMIT_NUM>}<ALL_BUT_ONE>*$`

The pattern means

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0*1){4}` - 4 repetitions of a sequence of patterns

  - `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
  - `1` - a `1` char
- `0*` - zero or more (`*`) `0` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That's worked for me, thanks!!